# How can i display 2 data label on 1 chart using chartjs and datalabel plugin

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to display a name of each chart outside of the chart and display it value inside the chart but it display only value of it on my code provide does i place the datalabels on the wrong place or something I should know ?

```
const configScoreChart = (lables = [], datasets = [], min = 0, max = 5, title = "") => {
        const data = {
            labels: datasets[0].labels,
            datasets: [{
                data: datasets[0].data,
                backgroundColor: datasets[0].backgroundColor,
                hoverOffset: 10,
                datalabels: {
                    labels: {
                        name: {
                            display: true,
                            color: 'black',
                            align: 'end',
                            anchor: 'end',
                            formatter: function(value, ctx) {
                            return ctx.chart.data.labels[ctx.dataIndex];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            }],
        };
        const config = {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: data,
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                tooltips: {
                    enabled: true,
                },
                plugins: {
                    datalabels: {
                        formatter: (value, ctx) => {
                            let sum = 0;
                            let dataArr = ctx.chart.data.datasets[ctx?.datasetIndex || 0].data;
                            dataArr.forEach(data => {
                                sum += (data ? parseInt(data) : 0);
                            });
                            let percentage = ((value ? parseInt(value) : 0) * 100 / sum).toFixed(2) + "%";
                            if (value > 0) {
                                return value;
                            } else {
                                return null;
                            }
                        },
                        color: '#000000',
                    },
                },
                animation: {
                    onComplete: () => {
                        CHART_SCORE = {
                            ...CHART_SCORE,
                            image: CHART_SCORE.chartJs.toBase64Image(),
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        };

        return config;
    };
```

I want to it to show both at the same time how can I fix it